# In Django QuerySet, how do I do negation in the filter?

Tags: django

Filtering QuerySets in Django work like the following:

```
Entry.objects.filter(year=2006)
```

How can I use filter to find all entries which does not have year 2006?  Something similar to the following sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM entries
WHERE not year = 2006
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`exclude()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude-kwargs) method:

```
>>> Entry.objects.exclude(year=2006)
```

Will return all Entry objects that are not in the year 2006.

If you wish to further filter the results, you can chain this to a filter() method:

```
>>> Entry.objects.exclude(year=2006).filter(field='value')
```